# How i can import a swf file into a canvas

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, preload, createjs

i want to import a swf file into my canvas
here is my cod

i have i function were i preload my swf

```
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, images;


function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    images = images||{};

    var manifest = [
        {src:"/...octo12.swf"},

    ];


    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
    loader.loadManifest(manifest);


    loader.onProgress = handleProgress;
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(22);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);

    var image = new createjs.Bitmap("/../logo.png");
    image.x = 300;
    image.y = 150;

    stage.addChild(image);

    var progress = new createjs.Shape();

    var progressBellow = new createjs.Shape();
    progress.graphics.beginStroke("#FF00FF").drawRect(450,440,500,30);
    progressBellow.graphics.beginStroke("#FF00FF").drawRect(450,440,500,30);
    // progress.graphics.setStrokeStyle(8,"round").beginStroke("#FFF");


    function handleProgress(event) {
        progress.graphics.clear();
        // Draw the progress bar
        progress.graphics.beginFill("#FF00FF").drawRect(450,440,500*(event.loaded / event.total),30);

    }

    stage.addChild(progress,progressBellow);
    stage.update();
}


function handleComplete() {
//================================stage==========================================================

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

//================================child==========================================================

    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();
    stage.enableMouseOver();

//================================ticker=========================================================

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
```

.
and i have home.html where i try to import them

```
<canvas id="canvas"  width="1300" height="800" style="max-height: 100%;height: 25%;width: 20%;margin-left:40%;margin-top: 15%">
    <object width="400" height="50" data="/..../swf/octo12.swf"></object>
</canvas>
```

import does not work, how can i import them into the canvas element
thx.

Comment: swf in a canvas? are you sure that's even possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a) embedding requires more attributes than that, including a clsid and a type. b) No OS has a "...." path - it's two dots at most. Good luck trying to get flash to appear inside the canvas, but I'm worried you might run into graphical conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [createjs.DomElement](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DOMElement.html) for this. Move your object out of the canvas element and give it an id.

```
   <canvas id="canvas"  width="1300" height="800"></canvas>
   <object id="myswf" width="400" height="50" data="/..../swf/octo12.swf"></object>
```

Then you could use the domElement to wrap it and add it to your stage like this (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
var domElement = new createjs.DOMElement($("#myswf"));
stage.addChild(domElement);
```